# D3.js - Create multi-ring donut chart dataset from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, graph

I have been trying to create a multi-ring donut chart by using following json.

```
var dataset = {
        weeks: [
            {"displayName": "MUW", "name": "DEF", "score": 5},
            {"displayName": "DEFA", "name": "DEF", "score": 35}
        ],
        trimester: [
            {"displayName": "MUsW", "name": "DEsF", "score": 25},
            {"displayName": "DEFdA", "name": "DEdF", "score": 5}
        ]
    };
```

But, it is not considering it as a proper dataset for D3's donut chart.

```
var gs = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.values(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
```

As I want to create two rings from this dataset one is on the top and the other one as an inner donut. And want to display the name on each click of donut slice.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcr3ogt4/ - code example.

Comment: Look through these links
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193 - simple donut(pie) chart;

http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-0-intro - working example with step-by-step development

Comment: I have already seen that but, I am willing to create a multi-ring donut chart. And as I have mentioned I had following dataset. Which is not recognized as the correct form of dataset through that command.

Comment: The code you provided is insufficient. The question is not clear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pcr3ogt4/ this is the link for fiddle

Comment: In the code you are making a single pie ... and the data you setting seems to be wrong _.data(d3.values(dataset))_ i believe you want to make a donut for weeks and other for trimesters

Comment: The code I have provided is for two graphs inner and outer one. But, it's not recognizing this dataset. I need help in providing this data structure to generate graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the data like this

```
.data(d3.values(dataset))
```

since your data set has two arrays., it does not mean it will draw two donut chart.

You will need to specify explicitly which of the two array will form the inner donut chart and which one outer donut chart.

For 1st donut chart you have to set the data like this:

```
.data(pie(dataset.weeks))//dataset for weeks
```

For 2nd donut chart you have to set the data like this:

```
.data(pie(dataset.trimester))//dataset for trimesters.
```

In your case you define the fie function like this:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);
```

It should have been like this the value function is missing which tells which value will form the criteria for the pie slice.

```
 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null).value(function (d) {
            return d.score;//since score is the parameter for the pie
        });
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/v231v7gb/).

**Note** on hover the text will be displayed.